# What to consider when starting a savings account for my children?

Tags: united-kingdom, savings, children

I want to start saving some money regularly for when my children turn 18.

What options are available to me and what are some things I need to consider when choosing the right approach?

Comment: What is the goal for the money? College? First Home? Teach them about saving? Something else?

Comment: @JohnFx, I don't have a specific goal in mind beyond just giving them a little help when they set out on their own. If they want to use if for college or a first home that is up to them and hopefully by that stage they would be mature enough to know how to use it wisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your specific goals, I'd suggest you review the choices at [Children's savings schemes and accounts](http://www.direct.gov.uk/en/MoneyTaxAndBenefits/ManagingMoney/PlanningYourPersonalFinances/DG_10014128). 
This site discusses the accounts for children and tax benefits for UK residents.

Comment: could you share similar links for the US please?

Answer (score 0):

I am interested in this idea too, and though I don't know anything about bringing up children and the costs associated with it, I would guess a good heuristic would be to assume that:

- you want to keep a separate account that you don't withdraw from (much), but deposit a certain percentage every now and then
- possibly have that account as interest bearing with a good yield-vs-risk ratio (is there a term for this in economics?)

CURRENT savings accounts, that do not require you to be engaged in the process, have yields anywhere from 0.05 - 3%.

I must ask: is that a good yield for you?